# How to hide some icons in System Settings?

Tags: configuration, customization, system-settings

I installed programs to  tweak  Ubuntu settings.  I found [a blog](http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/06/25-things-i-did-after-installing-ubuntu.html) that gave me good ideas, and also a good place to start.

The problem is that these programs that I was installing in my computer to tweak, installed an icon in the System Settings.

How to remove the icons of the following programs: MyUnity, Skype Wrapper Settings, Ubuntu One, Ubuntu Tweak.

Comment: What programs? If you want to remove the programs, then uninstall them.

Comment: I would rather keep the programs, but only remove the icons.  I have modified the question to include the programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove icons from the System Settings, you have to edit the `.desktop` file.

For example we will use `ubuntu-tweak`

Run:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop
```

Find and remove

> X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=ubuntu-tweak

then save the file, open System Settings, and they are now gone.

**Note**: Some applications might get rehoused after an update. The `.desktop` might get updated to the newer version, with the `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel` setting back in the file.

---

The steps above can be applied on any application that house them selfs in the control center.

**Further reading**

- [Unity Launchers And Desktop Files - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Comment: Great, this is just what I needed.

Comment: You should copy the `.desktop` file into the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory before editing it. Updates will overwrite changes to the files in `/usr/share/applications/`.

Comment: @dobey, I was thinking about that myself. But, when i edited the file the ubuntu tweak icon was still in the Control Center. It seems that the Control Center only reads the file from `/usr/share/applications/`? Thats what I concluded anyways.